# Moving a div inline with textfield

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have a 'add' button that duplicates my field, however i need this icon to be inline with my textfield as shown below, I have been messing about with the icon for a while now and i cant seem to get it inline, i have tried adding grids and removing but still no luck

[image]

As you can see the add button needs to be in line with contactEmails to make it more visually appealing

```
 {emails.map((email, i) => (
    <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
      <TextField
        className={classes.field}
        id="contactEmails"
        name="contactEmails"
        label="Contact Email(s)"
        fullWidth
        // onChange={change.bind(null, 'contactEmails')}
        autoComplete="lname"
        inputProps={{
          maxLength: 250
        }}
        value={emails[i]}
        onChange={e => setEmails(
          emails.map((email, j) => (i === j ? e.target.value : email))
        )}
      />
    </Grid>
  ))}
  <Fab className={classes.addButton} style={{ marginRight: 10, marginBottom: 10, backgroundColor: '#3B70BC', color: 'white' }} onClick={() => setEmails([...emails, ''])}> <Add /> </Fab>

 addButton: {
marginTop: theme.spacing.unit * 2,
color: '#3B70BC'
 }
```

Comment: provide a valid code man! we can't help you with this code!

Comment: @adel this is the code relating to the issue though, infact its all of the code

Comment: Is it material-ui? you should mention it

Comment: yes sorry it is material-UI

Answer (score 0):

You need to structure your items inside the `Grid` container, refer to [Grid](https://material-ui.com/components/grid/) docs.

Because you didn't show all related code, here is a generic example:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { TextField, Fab, Grid } from '@material-ui/core';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Grid container spacing={3} style={{ margin: '1%' }}>
      <Grid item>
        <TextField />
      </Grid>
      <Grid item>
        <Fab />
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit Q-56849818]

Answer (score 0):

- Delete `fullWidth` property in your `TextField` and don't use `Grid`.

Or

- If you wish to use Grid, you shall put the `<Fab>` component as an `item` in `Grid container`. `xs` prop specifies the space that the component will take in a total scale of 12 points for extra small displays. If you don't specify other sizes like `sm` or `md`, `xs` will apply to all sizes of display. Like this:

```
    <Grid container>
      <Grid item xs={9}>
        <TextField />
      </Grid>
      <Grid item xs={3}>
        <Fab />
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
```

Personnaly, I would not use Grid there, I would use [flexbox](https://flexboxfroggy.com/).